# Algorithms or libraries to convert the result of a query to JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, sql, object

I have a simple database schema with parent-child relationships, 2 to 3 levels deep. For example:

- School has many teachers
- School has many departments

I have a query that retrieves the school along with its teachers and departments as a flat table like this:

```
school  teacher  department
CMU     John     Engineering
CMU     Julie    Engineering
CMU     John     Humanities
CMU     Julie    Humanities
```

I know there are ORM tools that return such a result as objects, but they are too heavy and provide more than what I need. Are there simple algorithms or libraries to convert this result to a hierarchy of objects, e.g. in JSON format:

```
{
    departments: [
        'Engineering',
        'Humanities'
    ],

    teachers: [
        'John',
        'Julie'
    ]        
}
```

or for a 3 level deep relationship (of course different query and different resultset):

```
{
    departments: [
        {
            name: 'Engineering',
            teachers: [
                'John',
                'Julie'
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Humanities',
            teachers: [
                'Mike',
                'Mary'
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other databases, but postgresql has some functions that directly organize query result into json format, you might be interested in [this article](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql)

Comment: Very interesting! I would love to explore this further, but currently I have lot invested in MySQL.